# What is the meaning of (owe nothing to ..)?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of (**owe nothing to ..**) in the following context?

The distinctive crises of midlife do not turn on a
pervasive skepticism about reasons or values, on philosophical
doubts so fundamental **they owe nothing to the
shape of human life**. They do not invoke a comprehensive
nihilism but more elusive conceptions of oneself and
the world. That is why they are philosophically intriguing.

Comment: What is your thought on this?

Comment: They **do not derive from / they are not based on  / that are not related to**

Comment: I first thought it means ( irrelevant/ not related) but I wasn’t sure. But now it’s very clear. Thank you so much!